# strange json_encode result returned in ajax callback

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

what I did

```
while ($obj = $post_items->fetch_object()) {
     echo json_encode($obj);

}
```

and console the callback, everything seem working good but I found the data isn't that correct. some object have property like post id and post_id, see below

[image]

how can that be?

Comment: Are you sure that’s not just a _displaying_ glitch? For example the letter `g` gets cut of at the bottom, so possible that `_` gets cut of too on some lines … if that’s not it, then the data you are fetching must already be wrong.

Comment: actually nothing wrong with the data, the console is weird. I checked the network tab, the data is perfect. U are right. damn I spent hours to figure why!! lol~